# memory leakage in inference of pytorch_pretrained_bert.BertForSequenceClassification python

Tags: memory-leaks, pytorch, cpu-usage, bert-language-model, inference

I'm facing memory leakage in the realtime inference of pytorch_pretrained_bert's BertForSequenceClassification model.

Although I'm using GPU but still CPU memory is exhausting

```
      tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)


      model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-          uncased", num_labels=num_labels)
      model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path,  map_location='cpu'))
      model.eval()
      model.to(device)
      input_ids = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x) for x in tokenized_texts]
    
      # Pad our input tokens
      input_ids = pad_sequences(input_ids, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", truncating="post", padding="post")
    
      attention_masks = []
    
      for seq in input_ids:
          seq_mask = [float(i>0) for i in seq]
          attention_masks.append(seq_mask)
    
      _inputs = torch.tensor(input_ids)
       _masks = torch.tensor(attention_masks)

      del input_ids
      del attention_masks
      gc.collect()
      torch.cuda.empty_cache()

      _data = TensorDataset(_inputs, _masks )#, _labels)
      _sampler = RandomSampler(_data)
      _dataloader = DataLoader(_data, sampler=_sampler, batch_size=batch_size,
                              shuffle=False, num_workers=2
                              )

      del _data
      del _sampler
      predictions =[]
      for batch in _dataloader:
          batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)

          with torch.no_grad():
             logits = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)
             logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
             predictions.append(logits)
             gc.collect()
             torch.cuda.empty_cache()
             del logits
```

model, b_input_ids and b_input_mask are mapped on gpu using .to(device)

Can anyone suggest me what can I do..  memory is increasing gradually

Comment: Are you training the model? If so can you provide the training code instead?

Comment: No I have already trained it successfully . this issue is occurring in inference

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code snippet, ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please see https://github.com/google-research/bert#out-of-memory-issues